# webkitRelativePath in angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

My angular app needs the webkitRelativePath for the backend. The code below doesn't work because you cannot call `.webkitRelativePath` on a FileList. This is a problem because I need to access the relative path of all the files in the list. I've tried accessing directly via the File element as shown [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/webkitRelativePath) but I'm getting an error saying that the property webkitRelativePath doesn't exist on the type File.  Anyone got any sugestion(s) or other ways I could access the relative paths in my component?

```
<input type="file" id="file" *ngIf="checkboxValue" (change)="handleFileInput($event.target.files, $event.target.files.webkitRelativePath)" webkitdirectory multiple>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The webkitRelativePath is private for some reason, so accessing it via a string literal directly in the component solves the issue.

```
file['webkitRelativePath'];
```